# Rigged fbx model deforms when exporting to fbx

Tags: mesh, armature, export, unity, .fbx

Before and after pictures, mesh deforms when I export it as FBX to Unity. I am using Blender 2.79, the model deforms in blender after it exports to fbx and when I import it to unity it is deformed as shown below. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Before]
before

[image: After]
after

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If you have more information or wish to add further details to your question edit your original post. Also have in mind that simply posting two screenshots of the issue is very insufficient to diagnose any problems you are facing

Comment: You closed my last post, what was I supposed to do?

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/this-question-already-exists